# how to upload an array of data from firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to upload array of data into firebase using flutter I do not know how to upload array of data from firebase please help me to solve this by providing some examples of codes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example to upload data to Firestore using Dart (Flutter):

```
static example() async {
    var array = ["item1", "item2"];
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.ref
        .collection("myCollection")
        .doc("myDocument")
        .set({"myArray": array});
  }
```

Find more about data types and firestore here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types